# ASP.Net MVC - Invalid SSL Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, ascx

We're using a custom control (ascx) to call an external aspx page. When this control is used in aspx, it works fine. However when it's used in a Asp.Net MVC page, we get the error -

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
It also gives 'Invalid certificate' error.

I don't want to return true for 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' as it's working with aspx.

Any idea why it's working with aspx but not MVC? Does aspx run differently (different user) when compared to mvc page when both are in same project?

Comment: There is no way to help without some sort of code that demonstrates the error. Clearly there is some difference how your "aspx" (I assume it is separate site) is setup vs. "MVC page"... Note that you an use ASPX pages in ASP.Net MVC site just fine - so  "working with aspx but not MVC" does not explain much...

Comment: Both the aspx and mvc page are in the same project. The same user control (with same values) is used in both. However we get the error in mvc page alone.  "@Html.Partial("usercontrolname")" in mvc                               <uc1:usercontrolname runat"server" ID="usercontrolId"/> in aspx